# Reformatting one table in order to combine it to another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I am currently working on a personal project, and I am having some trouble combining two tables together. It is a project about NBA basketball game data. Stackoverflow won't let me add the tables to this  post, so I will attach screenshots of the tables:

[image: Here are the two tables I would like to combine]

My goal is to use the top table to create `total_STL`, `total_BLK`, `total_TO` for the home game and away game of each GAME_ID, and add it to the bottom table of the screenshot above.

The bottom table in the screenshot is called `games` and has `GAME_ID`as the primary key, and each row contains details about the stats of the home and away team. The top table I queried  on my own  [From this table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zl9kI.png) called `dbo.games_details`using the code:

```
SELECT GAME_ID, TEAM_abbreviation, TEAM_ID,
        SUM(CAST(STL as decimal)) AS total_STL, 
        SUM(CAST(BLK as decimal)) AS total_BLK,
        SUM(CAST(games_details.TurnOvers as decimal)) AS total_TO
FROM games_details
WHERE games_details.STL != ' ' and games_details.STL is not NULL
GROUP BY GAME_ID, TEAM_ID, TEAM_ID, TEAM_ABBREVIATION
ORDER BY game_ID desc

SELECT * FROM games
```

My approach to this problem was to first query and group `game_details` so it is more organized, obtaining the steals, blocks, and turnovers for each GAME_ID for both teams. Then I wanted to use the `games` table to somehow separate the teams into the HOME and AWAY team, and then create `total_STL_HOME`, and `total_STL_AWAY`
just like the other stats in `game_details`. However, I am fairly new to SQL and I am not entirely sure how to do this, since I believe this involves some pivoting  of some sort since I believe the rows are what I need to turn into columns in the other table.

To summarize everything:

`games`: table that contains GAME_ID as primary key. Each row contains details of away and home game stats of one team

`games_details`: foreign key as GAME_ID. Contains data of individual player on both teams for every game

My goal is to use `games_details` table to  add to  get the STL, TurnOvers, BLKS for the home and away teams, and to add it into `games` table.

Comment: Sorry i'm fairly new to this, I am not sure what you mean by  overriding the edit.

Comment: OH I was confused at first because I was not sure where that change came from so I fixed it. Did not know others could change it. Thank you for your clarification, I will fix that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My goal is to use the top table to create total_STL, total_BLK, total_TO for the home game and away game of each GAME_ID, and add it to the bottom table of the screenshot above.

I'm not sure what the screen shots have to do with your sample code.  But the idea looks like two joins:

```
select b.*, th.total_stl, th.total_blk, th.total_to,
       ta.total_stl, ta.total_blk, ta.total_to
from bottomtable b join
     toptable th
     on b.home_team_id = t.team_id join
     toptable tb
     on b.away_team_id = t.team_id
```

Comment: The sample code was just to show how I created the top table of the screenshot. I should probably delete the code as I already have the table.  Thank you.

I understand the first join, you are joining the top table with the bottom table based on home_team_id and team_id, but can you explain what the second join is?  I'm confused about the "toptable tb on b.away_team_id = t.team_id". What is toptable tb?

Comment: @darkfood4 . . . It is two joins to the same table, one for the home team and one for the away team.